# Maximum Subarray Problem Algorithm that uses divide and conquer but runs in linear time

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, optimization, divide-and-conquer

I am trying to design an algorithm that computes the largest (by sum) contiguous subarray of an array of size n that uses a divide and conquer approach, but runs in linear time. The standard divide and conquer approach runs in O(nlogn) (can be found in chapter 4 of CLR) which is not what I am looking for. The following describes an O(n) divide and conquer algorithm: Page 16 https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/d/4/1/d/8/10.1.1.150.7202.pdf however it goes over my head a little. Would anyone be able to shed some light on it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem, http://algorithmist.com/index.php/Kadane%27s_Algorithm, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/43852/755, http://stackoverflow.com/q/7943903/781723.

Comment: What is it that you don't understand. "I've read one explanation and I don't understand it; please give me another one!" isn't a good question, because the likely outcome is that somebody spends their time writing your another description of what the algorithm does, and you say "Sorry, don't understand that, either."